# How to achieve unique auto-incremented id for rows across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I've got several tables in a database, let's say they're called table1, table 2, etc.
All tables have a primary key column 'id' with auto-increment.

In my current configuration it happens that when inserting into table1, the generated id is 1.
Afterwards when inserting into table2, the generated id happens to be 1 as well.

How to force absolutely unique ids across all tables in a database? I want when inserting into table1, generated id to be 1, and if afterwards inserting into table2, generated id be 2?

I used mysql server on some machine and did not have this problem, but when I installed mysql on my local machine, it started to occur. So I guess it must be some kind of a setting that is applied to the mysql configuration?

Thank you

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you need that ?

Comment: You'll need an id table.  Instead of autgenerating the id in each individual table, grab the next id from the id table, then increment the value in the id table.

Comment: @legendinmaking because of limitations in the application layer

Comment: what if you check the `last_Inserted_Id` from table1 and when in table2 sum `table1.id+1`? It could work fine.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on how big you expect your tables to get, you can set the AUTO_INCREMENT = VALUE for each table.  EG. Table A starts at 10000000  Table B starts at 20000000.  As long as you have a large enough gap between the start values to support the expected size of the table.

Comment: @MichaelGardner your first suggestion is good. However if I set offsets to ids as you suggest in your second comment is not a good practice. You get yourself limited and it may become hard to scale.

Comment: @MartinAsenov - I agree, it's not the best practice, but it requires minimal code changes, and is quick to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use UUID.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, name) VALUES(SELECT UUID(), 'some data');
```

Read more about UUID: http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20MySQL%20With%20GUID%20or%20UUID

Comment: is there a way to achieve this with bigint type ids?

Comment: @MartinAsenov If you want to use bigint, you can try Michael Gardner suggestion. Use a separate id table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SEQUENCE which can be used globally.

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE serial
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 200
  START 364
  CACHE 1;
```

Edit: Sequences are supported in Postgres but this can be achieved in MySql by setting value for AUTO_INCREMENT and one can use LAST_INSERT_ID(). [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm)

Comment: There are no sequences in MySQL

Comment: @MartinAsenov: Good to pointing out. I written like I was writing for Postgres.